# How to get all documents from a particular chunks in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

From mongos log, I got the following message

```
 balancer move failed: { chunkTooBig: true, estimatedChunkSize: 408839903, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "chunk too big to move" } from: shard4 to: shard1
```

I know this issue occurs due to either

1. documents size to large,
2. index key not granular enough, and/or
3. chunkSize too small

While I'm confident that case 2 and 3 are not the cause, I want to see whether someone abuses the database by inserting extra large documents.

The mongos log shows the docs are in the range :

`min: { Country:"US", City:"LA" } max: { Country:"US": City:"NY" }`

```
min: { Country:"FR", City:"Paris" } max: { Country:"US": City:"New York" }
```

I want to aggregate the schema of documents within this range, and see if some documents contain extra fields.

Since the indexes are not monotonically increasing, I can't get all documents within this range (or can i?).

How can I

1. get the chunkID with the query

> db.coll.find({ Country:"US", City:"LA" })
>
> get all the docs within this chunk?
>
> Other suggestions are welcome.
>   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> use config show collections
>
> db.chunks.findOne()
>
> use config db.settings.save({_id: "chunksize", value: 2})
>
> sh.status()

Answer (score 0):

Your chunk size is 390M and is what MongoDB calls jumbo chunk. Your shard key is not good. It creates hotspots since some cities seems to hold more data than others.

For the chunk you referring to, if there is no other city with Country:"US" between LA and NY in your dataset the balancer (or you) is not able find a split point.

You don't need the chunk id to find how many documents are in the chunk has, you can execute:

db.col.find({Country:"US", City:{$gte:"LA"} , City:{$lte:"NY"} } )

Comment: How should I modify the query if the docs are in range
min: { Country:"FR", City:"Paris" } max: { Country:"US": City:"New York" }?

Comment: You have both City:NY and City:"New York" to your data-set?

Comment: sorry, let me edit my question